# Whats the Kotlin Syntax called where you have two names after var or val: var (name1, name2) =

Tags: android, kotlin, variables

I downloaded a project and I'm not really sure what exactly the following line does:

```
val (episode, setEpisode) = remember { mutableStateOf<EpisodeDetail?>(null) }
```

The only thing I don't get is why there are two names after the "val" word.
I tried to google for it but I really don't know the name of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a Destructuring Declaration

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

You may have seen something similar in JavaScript when you have an object, and you can extract the keys to variables with the following

```js
const { key1, key2 } = { key1:"first", key2:"second", ignored:"third" };
console.log(key1, key2) // first second
```

If you have a data class Kotlin will create the component<N> functions for you.

```
class MyClass (val myStr: String, val myInt: Int, val myBool: Boolean) {
    operator fun component1(): String = myStr
    operator fun component2(): Int = myInt
    operator fun component3(): Boolean = myBool
}

fun main() {
    val x = MyClass("Hello", 5, false)
    val (y, _, z) = x // use _ to ignore values you don't need
    println(y) // Hello
    println(z) // false
}
```

Unlike Javascript which uses the key names, Kotlin data classes use field ordering (by defining your own component<N> functions you could swap the order of destructuring).